# build library for iphone simulator setting the right architecture

Tags: ios, sdl

I have problem that when building a lot library such as sdl,and irrlicht, when I build the armv6 and armv7 it works fine,but when I change architectures to i386(simulator right?),it says warning no rules to process source file name for architecture i386, I can see there's a lot error that happens when compilling .h files? header file doesn't need to compile right?

but it compiles fine with armv7 and armv6 for device. so my questions are :
1.How to solve that? do I need to remove each .h ?
2.when compilling sdl for simulator it says the same thing even compilling .c files.

Comment: You dont have to change any of that. Just leave them the way they were when you created the project.

Comment: You are not supposed to include header files within the files to compile (Target->Build Phase->Compile Sources) - only implementation files (c, m, mm, cc, cpp, etc) should be listed. **Note** that does not mean that those should not be included within the project.